# How to handle two similar webhook at the same time?

Tags: github, webhooks

We have a service based on GitHub.

GitHub sends us two same webhook exactly at the same time for a specific event. On my server every webhook (event) is treated as an action, but when I receive those two events at the same time, the action is being created twice.

In your opinion what is the best way to handle this case?

For now the solution I came up with is the following:

```
 1. My Server receives a webhook
 2. Wait a few seconds
 3. Create an id for that webhook
 4. Check that this ID doesn't exist in my DB
 5. Create an entry in my DB with that ID
```

The problem with this solution is that when I receive it exactly at the same time it doesn't work.

Any thought would be appreciated!

Thank you